# Convert ArrayList<HashMap> to ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to convert an `ArrayList<HashMap>` to an `ObservableList` and place it in my `TableView`. Placing the items in the `TableView` works, it just doesn't display the values from the `HashMap`. So, for an `ArrayList` that has `6` items, `6` rows show in the table, but the cells contain empty values.

Here is what I have:

```
@FXML
TableView dataTable;

//... Other code ...//

ArrayList<HashMap> items = currentMysqlConn.getTableData(databaseName, tableName, 1000);
ObservableList<HashMap> oblist = FXCollections.observableArrayList(items);

dataTable.setItems(oblist);

//... Other code ...//
```

Comment: Show the cell value factories you have defined.

Comment: I don't have any....

Comment: What do you expect the TableView to display?  How do you expect it to render a cell with a HashMap value?

Comment: I am grabbing data from a mysql database, so as I look at examples it seem as if the items are already set like the table developer already knows the number of columns and what those columns are. As for me I have no idea how many columns there will be or what the columns are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it!

This blog post is exactly what I was trying to display:

http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/

Comment: please mark this as the correct answer, so it is not unanswered anymore!